# How to get the entire text when user taps on UItextview in Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextView with names in it some thing like this.

Founders:  Eduardo Saverin, Chris Hughes, Dustin Moskovitz, Mark Zuckerberg, Andrew McCollum

When user clicks on any of the name then i need to get that name and pass as a parameter to a API Call.
Can some one please let me know how to implement this functionality.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want to get the **selected** text then you should change the subject of you post. You asked how to get the **entire** text. Both codingVoldemort and I took that to mean that you really wanted all the text.

Answer (score 1):

@codingVoldemort posted an answer, then deleted it for some reason.

The answers that your textView has a property text that gives you the entire contents:

```
[target callMethodWithText: yourTextView.text];
```

### EDIT:

If you want the selected text then use the text view's selectedRange property to get the range of the selection, and NSString substring methods like substringWithRange to extract that portion of the string.

If you want to be notified when the user changes the selection, implement the delegate method `textViewDidChangeSelection`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need the text which user clicks on it. If user clicks on the Name "Chris Hughes" then i need to get that text.

Comment: See my edit. I explain how to get the selected text.

Answer (score 1):

UITextview passes below message to its delegate when a text selection in UITextview is changed. You need to implement this in the textview delegate class.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
NSRange selectedRange = textView.selectedRange;
NSString *selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:selectedRange];
NSLog(@"\nSelected Text is:\n %@", selectedText);
```

}